# flash to html5 fallback for a file (no video)

Tags: flash, html

I have several Flash animations (maps with buttons that show/hide layers, slideshows, etc.). I'm looking for a code that loads in the first time a Flash animation (file.swf) and, if it couldn't be showed/loaded (i.e. in iOS devices), fallback to a HTML5 file. (file.html; maybe inside an iframe)

I'm converting some SWF to HTML5 with Swiffy, but results are not always OK. So, I prefer trying to load the SWF file in the first time.

All codes I've found are for videos and audios. I don't know how to adapt them to work with SWF and HTML files, instead of SWF and MP4/OGG.

Any suggestion will be welcome. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [SWFObject](http://blog.deconcept.com/swfobject/#howitworks) which is the standard method of embedding Flash in a webpage. If you're using CS5 you can change your publish settings so that the HTML which is generated includes the SWFObject code automatically (see [this tutorial](http://www.cloudninecreative.co.uk/flash/how-to-publish-as-html-swfobject-with-flash-cs5/)).

This method will allow you to [progressively enhance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progressive_enhancement) your page by replacing the contents of a specific div, which should contain your fall-back method, with your Flash content, but only if the user's browser supports Flash. This method will work for any browser / device which does not support Flash.

Comment: Thank you net.uk.sweet. This solution worked for me. 
I'm not using CS5, but I could apply the script